# Angular 8 Telemetry Sharing Opt-In

Tags: angular, sharing, angular8, telemetry

I would like to know, how to opt-in for sharing the telemetry-data which is one new feature in Angular 8.

I already read a lot about the new features in Angular 8 and as part of those feature about the opt-in sharing options for the usage data of the framework. But there was no explanation where to toggle the switch.

I guess it could be some property to set in the angular.json of a project, like telemetry-sharing: true or something, but did not find anything like this so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://angular.io/cli/usage-analytics-gathering):

`ng config --global cli.analyticsSharing.tracking $YOUR_TRACKING_KEY`